# How to fix this "sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1:" exception?

Tags: maven, dependencies, sbt

I just clone the project [scala-js-react](https://github.com/xored/scala-js-react), and run `sbt`, it reports some error about dependency.

I tried to fix it by add some resolvers, but no lucky.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/xored/scala-js-react.git
$ cd scala-js-react
$ sbt
```

Reports error:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/twer/workspace/scala-js-react/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/twer/workspace/scala-js-react/project/}scala-js-react-build...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-fccfbd44c9f64523b61398a0155784d[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: configuration not found in commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.6 compile
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
[warn]        +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6
[warn]        +- org.xerial.sbt:sbt-sonatype:0.2.1 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (/Users/twer/workspace/scala-js-react/project/plugins.sbt#L3-4)
[warn]        +- default:scala-js-react-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: configuration not found in commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.6 compile
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:278)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:175)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:157)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:151)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:151)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:128)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:56)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:64)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:64)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:123)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:120)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:151)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:157)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1318)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1315)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$85.apply(Defaults.scala:1345)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$85.apply(Defaults.scala:1343)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1342)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1360)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1300)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1275)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: configuration not found in commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.6 compile
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Comment: same here, any update?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just deleted the `commons-logging` from local `~/.ivy2/cache`, and re-run it.

PS: I don't know why it can fix it :(

Comment: I just ran into the same problem and this solution indeed works. I'd like to know why. Can you explain?

Comment: Helped for me too, but I'd be really happy to know what causes this.

Comment: I had to remove the cache directory but ultimately worked. If I hadn't burnt an hour on this I might have appreciated the irony a bit more.

Comment: Things like this keep me from liking sbt :(

Answer (score 1):

I fell into the exactly same problem of `commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1`. Thanks to Freewind, I just delete *ivy-3.2.1.xml* and *ivydata-3.2.1.properties* and it works correctly.

I believe, at least in my case, these metadata files are corrupted but have *no* evidence to prove.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it is late but I had the same problem and above answers did not fix it
What I did  : 
in project folder 
edit build.properties and changed sbt.version from 0.13.5 to 0.13.6

```
#Activator-generated Properties
#Tue Sep 09 12:46:06 CEST 2014
template.uuid=5f91b045-ad7c-4a08-b31e-3f5ea4bacb81
sbt.version=0.13.6
```

=> it now goes to https://rep1.maven... instead of http) so it could update the missing libs and ivy2

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a line to the Build.scala file, 
.settings(resolvers += "Guardian Github io repos" at "https://guardian.github.io/maven/repo-releases/")

Looks like there was a change from http to https and from .com to .io

Answer (score 0):

Manually include the library in .ivy2/cache and try again.

Comment: better as a comment